# Using TabbarViewController the preferredStatusBarStyle not called

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabbarViewController with different views, the problem is:

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
          return .lightContent
      }
```

not called in any the of the views.

I have tried to add:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return selectedViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? selectedViewController
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? topViewController
    }
}
```

Nothing change, should I call this extension method in some where else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a class of UInavigation Controller then add this methods to the class and it start to work.

```
 override open var childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return self.topViewController
    
}
   
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add in to `Info.plist` expect adding some codes.

[image]

You can basically add this into your `Info.plist`